# Style is not showing in Google org chart

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

```
$table = array();
$str = '<b>BB</b>';
$table['cols'] = array(
array("id"=>"","label"=>"Name","pattern"=>"","type"=>"string"),
array("id"=>"","label"=>"Manager","pattern"=>"","type"=>"string"),
array("id"=>"","label"=>"Tooltip","pattern"=>"","type"=>"string")
);
$rows = array();
$temp = array();
$temp[] = array("v"=>"BB","f"=>"BB");
$temp[] = array("v"=>null,"f"=>null);
$temp[] = array("v"=>null,"f"=>null);


$rows[] = array('c' => $temp,'p'=>'{style: border: 2px solid #D1D0CE;}');
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
```

'p'=>'{style: border: 2px solid #D1D0CE;}' this style is not showing in Google org chart.
Actually it is showing the error jQuery error "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand c

without it the org chart is showing fine. What is the proper format to give p: tag.

My client side code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['orgchart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "getData.php",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
            }).responseText;


            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new       google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, {allowHtml: true});
        }

    </script>
</head>
```

This is my json response.

```
{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Name","pattern":"","type":"string"},       {"id":"","label":"Manager","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Tooltip","pattern":"","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"BB","f":"BB"},{"v":null,"f":null},{"v":null,"f":null}],"p":"{style: 'border: 2px solid #D1D0CE;'}"}]}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need quotes around style, `{style: "border: 2px solid #D1D0CE;"}` - but the PHP code and produced JSON is OK. We need to see how you process the result from PHP, not the PHP itself, since the error is generated clientside.

Comment: Tried that!! Still no result.

Comment: What does the row vardump look like

Comment: {"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Name","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Manager","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Tooltip","pattern":"","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"BB","f":"BB"},{"v":null,"f":null},{"v":null,"f":null}],"p":"{style: 'border: 2px solid #D1D0CE;'}"}]}

Comment: I am still stuck on it!!!

Comment: please someone help me out